# Javascript attributes not changing after once they have changed already

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where I display streaming videos (WebRTC Conference) dynamically and for that I also have to set there video element size dynamically depending on number of videos.

I realized that my javascript code only changes the size of video elements only once (when I apply it for the first time). Or may be I am doing something wrong. Because it works fine if I hardcode number of videos (only html and js; no webrtc) and js has to set their size in one go (at once).. my webrtc code is in a way that in beginning its always one video, as it loops through (when new video comes in) then my code not able to handle the size of all elements.

My code:

```
// I have to reuse this code everytime I have to change size (properties) of all video tags in the document

function layout() {
    for(var i=0;i<videoIds.length;i++){ // I've tried with ids
        var localView = document.getElementById(videoIds[i]);
        localView.setAttribute('position', 'relative');
        localView.setAttribute('height', '50vh');
        localView.setAttribute('width', '50vw');
        localView.setAttribute('object-fit', 'cover');
    }
    
    var localView = document.getElementsByClassName('class'); // I've tried with class name
    for(var i=0;i<localView.length;i++){
        localView.setAttribute('position', 'relative');
        localView.setAttribute('height', '50vh');
        localView.setAttribute('width', '50vw');
        localView.setAttribute('object-fit', 'cover');
    }
    
    var localView = document.getElementsByTagName('video'); // I've tried with tag name
    for(var i=0;i<localView.length;i++){
        localView.setAttribute('position', 'relative');
        localView.setAttribute('height', '50vh');
        localView.setAttribute('width', '50vw');
        localView.setAttribute('object-fit', 'cover');
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything here? please help.

Is it possible that my code is not getting completed by the time code is re-called again, or some how code is skipped. Example:

```
const initSelfStream = (id) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                {
                    //video: { facingMode: selectedCamera },
                    video: video_constraints,
                    audio: true
                }).then(stream => {
                    const video = document.createElement("video");
                    loadAndShowVideoView(video, stream, localId);
                });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('(async () =>: ' + err);
        }
    })();
}
initSelfStream(id);

// Some Code

pc.ontrack(e){
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    loadAndShowVideoView(video, e.tracks[0], remoteId);
}

const loadAndShowVideoView = (video, stream, id) => {
    if(totalUsers.length == 1){
        console.log('Currently ' + totalUsers.length + ' User Are Connected.');
        video.classList.add('video-inset', 'background-black');
        video.setAttribute("id", id);
        video.style.position = "absolute"
        
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.style.height = 100+"vh"
        video.style.width = 100+"vw"
        
        video.muted = true;
        video.style.objectFit = "cover"
        
        appendVideo(video, stream);
    } else if(totalUsers.length == 2){
        // I add new video with desirable height & width
        // Then call and run original function on the top with element number & condition
         layout('8 videos', "size should be 25vh, 25vw");
    }
}

const appendVideo = (video, stream) => {
    container.append(video);
    video.play()
}
```

Html is very simple. One div in body that contain videos:

```
<body>
    <div class="views-container background-black" id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add required HTML too. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share how you are calling this function.

Comment: Some of these attributes should be CSS, and are not valid attributes.

Comment: Set using the style property instead localView.style.height = ......

Comment: @TusharShahi, I have just updated the code

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass, just added HTML

Comment: You should add the code as a Stack Snippet... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine all style attributes. Instead of:

```
video.style.position = "absolute"
video.style.height = 100+"vh"
video.style.width = 100+"vw"
video.style.objectFit = "cover"
```

You can:

```
video.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; object-fit: cover;);
```

And since you already uses css classes, you don't have to repeat it over on your conditions and just:

```
video { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; obejct-fit: cover; }
```

Now you can change `width` and `height` with `setAttribute`.

Comment: May be I am doing something wrong. Because it works fine if I hardcode number of videos (only html and js; no webrtc) and js has to set their size in one go (at once).. my webrtc code is in a way that in beginning its always one video, as it loops through (when new video comes in) then my code not able to handle the size of all elements.

Comment: Where you get `totalUsers.length`? is this the same number as videos? Try count this length and if it changes - execute function again.

Comment: Yes, `totalUsers` is an array of ids of users in conference and yes the number of videos.